# How can get an number in the string with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I simply want to get `15` in a string like:

```
countryNo=-1&count=15&page=2
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Will the string always be formatted exactly like that, or could there be other variables before it?  Are you actually asking how you get a value from a querystring?  The answer to what you've actually asked is `var value = "15";` so please be clearer about what you want.

Comment: "countryNo=-1&count=15&page=2" this will serve what you need,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/vp9PH/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
var myQuery = getQueryVariable('count');

function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0] == variable) 
            return pair[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var x = "countryNo=-1&count=15&page=2";
var n = /(?:^|&)count=(\d+)/.exec(x)[1];
```

Comment: Oops, your code broke: `something=5&other-count=6&count=7`

Comment: That will then break if you had `count=5&xyz=7`

Comment: @andy The problem is that no body knows if the format of the target string could vary as this might open a lot of potentials.

Comment: @andy Problem fixed, although as I say no body can tell the true format.

Comment: True, Parsing anything with Regex is hard :p

Answer (score 1):

`'other-count=155&count=175&page=2'.match(/(&|^)count\=([0-9]+)/)`

is the code you want. It'll return an array containing: `count=15` and `15` on its own.

You'll want to grab the *last* value from the returned array that contains the number on its own.

```
function extract_count(string) {
  match = string.match(/[&|^]count\=([0-9]+)/)

  return (match.length != 0) ? match[match.length-1] : null;
}
```

That will return 175 in the above example.

Comment: Oops, your code broke: `something=5&other-count=6&count=7`

Comment: Fair point! Just the simplest way I thought of doing it. @Arnaldo's answer is probably better in this case.

Comment: Updated it so it works now

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string up into parts and create an associative array.

```
var q = "countryNo=-1&count=15&page=2";

var vars = [], hash;
    if(q != undefined){
        q = q.split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < q.length; i++){
            hash = q[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[1]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
}

var count = vars['count'];
```